Test should fail on Error with StandardTestDispatcher / viewModelScope
I am testing a viewmodel which is launching coroutines with its viewModelScope. Since the viewmodelscope is created with a supervisorjob internally, throwables are just logged. That is a problem for unit tests, since tests are passing, even though there is an error.
Since the viewModelScope is a val, it can not be changed. In Dispatchers.setMain I can not add a CoroutineExceptionHandler, since the function does not take a CoroutineScope. I do not want to change the production code for a unit test.
How can I assert that there is no error thrown?

